# How to redirect to process to go?

Tags: asp.net, mobile, desktop-application

I want to know if the user comes from the desktop or from mobile.
If it's from mobile - make redirect to Process to go.

Can you help me please?

Comment: I don't know what "redirect to Process to go" means. Can you clarify that? And why not just build a responsive site instead of sending mobile users elsewhere? What does this have to do with desktop-application tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know *Boolean* value, you could just use the following helper method.

*If you want to know more details about the requested device, you will need to use third party library like [51Degrees](https://51degrees.com/).*

```
public static bool IsMobileBrowser(HttpContext context)
{
    // first try built in asp.net check
    if (context.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // then try checking for the http_x_wap_profile header
    if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE"] != null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // then try checking that http_accept exists and contains wap
    if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"] != null &&
        context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"].ToLower().Contains("wap"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Finally check the http_user_agent header variable for any one of the following
    if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] != null)
    {
        // List of all mobile types
        string[] mobiles =
            new[]
            {
                "android", "opera mini", "midp", "j2me", "avant", "docomo", "novarra", "palmos", "palmsource",
                "240×320", "opwv", "chtml",
                "pda", "windows ce", "mmp/", "blackberry", "mib/", "symbian", "wireless", "nokia", "hand", "mobi",
                "phone", "cdm", "up.b", "audio", "sie-", "sec-", "samsung", "htc", "mot-", "mitsu", "sagem", "sony",
                "alcatel", "lg", "eric", "vx", "nec", "philips", "mmm", "xx", "panasonic", "sharp", "wap", "sch",
                "rover", "pocket", "benq", "java", "pt", "pg", "vox", "amoi", "bird", "compal", "kg", "voda",
                "sany", "kdd", "dbt", "sendo", "sgh", "gradi", "dddi", "moto", "iphone"
            };

        // Check if the header contains that text
        var userAgent = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].ToLower();

        return mobiles.Any(userAgent.Contains);
    }

    return false;
}
```